# Allow a specfik page to be found by search engines

Tags: magento-1.9, seo

I'm using a `custom plugin` for a case designer. It is placed in the `app` folder. But through my `robots.txt` that folder is disallowed for search engines.

The plugin is showing a page from a folder here

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/personaliseit/products
```

***Is it just so simple to allow that full path now that i have disallowed app?***

I don't want everything else indexed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [robot.txt to disallow all pages except one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869004/robot-txt-to-disallow-all-pages-except-one-do-they-override-and-cascade)

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /under-construction
Disallow: /
```

You could also add below to all page except

```
<reference name="head">
   <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW</value></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Thx for that :)